# Unable to add parameters that are not defined in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Can I add new parameter in mongodb collection, which are not defined in mongoose schema?
Here is my schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    FirstName : {
        type : String       
    },
    LastName : {
        type : String
    },
    ProfileName : {
        type : String
    },
    EmailID : {     //This may actually take Phone Number depending on user account.
        type : String,
        required : true     
    },
    Login : {
        type : { enum : ['Facebook', 'Gmail', 'Custom'] },
        required : true     
    },
    ContactNumber : 
    {
        type : Number
    },
    Address : {  //Add Geo co-ordinates location later.
        type : {}
    },
    ProfilePic : {
        type : String   //URL to image
    },
    Birthday : {
        type : {}      
    },
    Gender : {
        type : { enum : ['Male', 'Female']}
    },
    CreatedDate : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    ModifiedDate : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now       
    },
    LastLogin : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now       
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UsersSchema);
```

And I want to add some parameters like **EmailVerified** and **MobileNumberVerified**
Here is my routes code which actually insert data in mongodb

```
router.post('/api/signup',function(req,res){
    console.log("Registering user");

    var user = new Users();
    user.FirstName = req.body.FirstName;
    user.LastName = req.body.LastName;
    user.EmailID = req.body.EmailID;
    user.Login = "Custom";
    user.Password = req.body.Password;
    user.ProfileName = req.body.FirstName + " " +req.body.LastName;
//    user.Birthday = 
    user.Address = req.body.Address;
    user.Gender = req.body.Gender;
    user.EmailVerified = false; // dynamic parameter
    user.MobileNumberVerified = false; // dynamic parameter

//    user.ContactNumber = req.body.ContactNumber;
    user.save(function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json(err);
        }else{
            console.log("User Registered");
            res.json({result : 1});
        }
    });

});
```

But in mongodb these fields are not present. I think mongoose doesn't permit dynamically adding parameters.

Comment: You should use mongoose virtuals http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html

Comment: Thanks @styopdev.  `Users.set("EmailVerified", false);` working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding paths to the model's schema after the model has been compiled is unsupported. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose allows dynamically adding parameters which are not present in schema. However it is disabled by default.

You can enable it by using **{ strict: false }** when defining model. See below code.

```
const thingSchema = new Schema({ /* ... */ }, { strict: false });
const thing = new Thing({ iAmNotInTheSchema: true });
thing.save(); // iAmNotInTheSchema is now saved to the db!!
```

Check out [this article](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict).